# Tests are not executed - Bot Issue: Test target MyTests encountered an error (Test session exited(0) without checking in

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xctest, osx-server

I'm using Xcode Continuous Integration for making builds.

OS X Server 4.1, 
Mac OS X 10.10.4, 
Xcode 6.3.1

My all test cases start failing after OS X update OS X 10.10.4 (Build 14E17e) and Xcode 6.3.2. I'm not sure whether these update cause the issue or something else.

**Error:** *Bot Issue: error. Uncategorized. Issue: Test target MyTests encountered an error (Test session exited(0) without checking in*

Any idea what is the cause of the issue?

**Observation:**
I ran test cases using xctool all the test cases are passing however when I ran test cases in release mode, they are failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My issue is resolved. I don't know the exact reason however I changed sign-in '-' to Don't SignIn in build setting of all tests targets and I found one crash while running test cases in released mode. My issue is resolved after fixing these two issues.